# C# iequatable == example, why use (object)myInstace to test null

Tags: c#, iequatable

So in one of the example given by C#.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.7.1

They add a `==`-operator in a class, but the part I don't understand is why they use `(object)target == null` to check for nullness, instead of `target == null`.

```
public static bool operator ==(PotentialGrabTarget target1, PotentialGrabTarget target2)
{
    //~~~~~ My Question is for the next line of code ~~~~~
    if (((object)target1) == null || ((object)target2) == null) //<<<<<<                         
        return System.Object.Equals(target1, target2);

    return target1.Equals(target2);
}
```

Comment: Because otherwise `target1 == null` will call the same `==` operator you are writing, resulting in infinite recursion.

Comment: A less obtuse way of writing this is `Object.ReferenceEquals(target1, null)`, which avoids any possibility of invoking an overload of anything.

Comment: ^^ Those comments should be an answer ...

Comment: @Evk, thank you for explaining, now it make sense,  would you mind putting this as the answer so i can accept it and finish the question?

Comment: @Libra question is correctly marked as duplicate, so posting answers is not possible (and not needed).